# How do I distinguish folder and files using MediaStore.files table?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am making File Explorer app using MediaStore.files table in android.
But I don't know how to distinguish them(file,folder) using files columns.

I already have used the way that use the new File().isDirectory() and that way give me a result that I want. But I don't want to use newFile() because of App performance.